# Combinatorial interpretation of $j$-canonical representation of naturals?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

In the paper

- P. McMullen (1971). The number of faces of simplicial polytopes. *Israel J. Math.* 9: 559-570

P. McMullen defines the $j$-canonical representation of a natural number $n$ as a particular representation

$$ n = \binom{n_j}{j}+\binom{n_{j-1}}{j-1} + \dots + \binom{n_i}{i} $$

satisfying $n_j>n_{j-1}>\dots>n_i\geq i\geq 1$, and asserts that it is the unique such representation satisfying this. I convinced myself that this assertion is true, using the [hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity). But I would love a more combinatorial way to understand what's going on.

**My question:** Is there a combinatorial interpretation of the numbers $i$ and $n_j,\dots,n_i$ that make clear what they are revealing about the pair $(n,j)$? (If so, what is it?)

**Further context:** Given $n,j$, one defines a number $n^{\langle j\rangle}$ by taking the $j$-canonical representation of $n$ and then setting

$$n^{\langle j\rangle} := \binom{n_j+1}{j+1}+\binom{n_{j-1}+1}{j} + \dots + \binom{n_i+1}{i+1} $$

This number is related (see Theorem 2.2 [here](http://math.mit.edu/%7Erstan/pubs/pubfiles/30.pdf)) to the the growth rate of Hilbert functions of standard-graded algebras over a field. I would like more intuition about what $n^{\langle j\rangle}$ is, and am hoping that an answer to the above question will help with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is inspired in the [Kruskal-Katona theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Katona_theorem#Statement_for_uniform_hypergraphs) stated in the form of Uniform hypergraphs. Let $[n]=\{1,2,\cdots ,n\}$ and consider the set $\binom{[m]}{j}=\{A\subseteq [m]:|A|=j\}$ of subsets of $[m]$ with fixed length $j.$ Take $m$ big enough such that $n\leq \binom{m}{j}.$ 
Now, consider the reverse lexicographic ordering on $\binom{[n]}{j}$ that is $$[j]\geq [j-1]\cup {j+1}\geq \cdots \geq [m]\setminus [m-j].$$ For example, for $m=3,j=2$ the list would be

1. $\{2,3\}$
2. $\{1,3\}$
3. $\{1,2\}$

Suppose that $A_n$ is the set that is exactly in position $n$ of the list of all these sets using the lexicographic order and take $$A_n=\{1\leq n_1<n_2<\cdots <n_j\},$$ is clear then that if $n_j$ is the maximum is because we already went thru all $\binom{n_j-1}{j}$ possibilities. Now fix $n_j,$ then we have to went over all $\binom{n_{j-1}-1}{j-1}$ possibilities so at the end of the day the $n-$th set is in position $$1+\sum _{k=1}^j\binom{n_k-1}{k}.$$
So the $\{n_j\}$ are the elements(indexed from $0$) of the set that is exactly at position $n$ when you order lexicographically the elements of $\binom{[m]}{j}$ for $m$ such that $\binom{m}{j}\geq n.$
**Note:** this is not much different than any base decomposition. Numbers are the same but the order is given by the order of the digits in the base.

Comment: Okay, I understand; this is extremely helpful. I have two questions. (1) It seems to me you actually mean the reverse lexicographic order? Because the argument requires that all $\binom{n_j-1}{j}$ $j$-subsets of $[n_j-1]$ be run through before any element gets to position $n_j$ (indexed from 0). So, e.g., {0,3} needs to come after {1,2}, even though it is lexicographically earlier. Correct? and (2) this description of the $n_j$ seems to me only to hold if $i=1$ and $n_i\neq i$ (in the OP's notation). For example if the $j$-set begins with a segment like {0,1,2}, then $i=n_i=3$, and 0,1,2 don't

Comment: occur as $n_k$'s. In general, if there are several consecutive integers in the "lowest" positions of the $j$-set, then instead of $n_k$'s corresponding to these integers we just have the single $n_i$ one bigger than the biggest of them, and $i$ is how many there are. Do I have this right? Do you have a more uniform way of understanding this, or do you just make this exception when there are several consecutive lowest numbers?

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith
(1) You are right, I meant the reverse lexicographic order. Thanks!
(2) I think your example corresponds to $0=\binom{2}{3}+\binom{1}{2}+\binom{0}{1}$ I will take $i$ to be the last index in which the binomial is not $0.$ So, for example, corresponding to $\{0,2,3\}$ instead of yours, the binomial is $2=\binom{3}{3}+\binom{2}{2}+\binom{0}{1}$ so I would take $i=2.$

Comment: Oh, you are also indexing the count of the sets themselves from zero? Maybe this is the uniform way I was asking for. I was thinking that {0,1,2,4} was the *second* set with $j=4$, and $2=\binom{4}{4}+\binom{3}{3}$. But you seem to be thinking of it as representing 1, so $1=\binom{4}{4}$, right?

Comment: If you count this way, you end up just ignoring the initial segment.

Comment: Yes! That is why I put a +1 in the expression at the end. Sorry for inconvenience trying to decipher it. I will try to write better later.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for all this, it was extremely clarifying.